# Distance at bottom of porch railings

Tags: stairs, railing

Is there a standard distance between steps and bottom of porch step railings? What I am referring to is if you measure the distance from a step to the railing above it. The distance I measured was around 10 inches.

Comment: Each City/Town/County in the US has codes for this. Example quick google: http://www.co.stevens.wa.us/landservices/documents/STAIRWAYSECTION.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an illustration, I presume you mean the sloped bottom rail that the balusters rest on of the stair hand rail system.

If I remember right, this is pretty much standard everywhere in the US.

This is a copy and paste from the pdf referred to by nobyman. His was handy, it saved time...

**R312.3 Guard opening limitations. Required guards shall not have openings from the walking surface to the required
guard height which allow passage of a sphere 4 inches (102 mm)in diameter.
 Exceptions:
 1. The triangular openings at the open side of a stair, formed by the riser, tread and bottom rail of
 a guard, shall not allow passage of a sphere 6 inches (153 mm) in diameter.
 2. Guards on the open sides of stairs shall not have openings which allow passage of a sphere**
 **4 3/8 inches (111 mm) in diameter.**

Comment: Evidently it did not save enough time, Lee Sam got there first

Answer (score 2):

The International Code Council says in the International Building Code that a 4" sphere shall not pass through a "guard" for stairs over 30" above finish floor...except for the triangular space formed by the riser, tread and bottom of the guardrail. In which case, it cannot allow a 6" sphere to pass. (There are other exceptions, but none that pertain to your issue.) See Section 1013.4, Exception 2 of the IBC.